# Insert the current date and time (DATETIME-function) with a single shortcut into a cell in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice-calc

I know there is the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> shortcut to insert the current date and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd> to insert the current time.

However I have two issues with that:

1) I would like to have one shurtcut for both

2) I would like to be able to use a custom date-time format (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`)

My language default format is `MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS pm/am` - I do **not** want to change this. I want to use a custom format specifically for that shortcut, preferably without solutions involving `xdotool` or similar external macro software or global system-wide shortcuts.

The functions within `Tools -> Customize -> Keyboard` don't seem to offer any help.

([Why I don't want to use xdotool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038038/xdotool-type-takes-ages-and-causes-entire-desktop-to-freeze); A solution directly within LibreOffice would be best.)

---

I found the following OpenOffice macro code [here](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php), but it says it only works with Writer documents. How would I modify this macro to insert the formatted DATE-TIME into the currently selected cell in Calc?

```vb
'Author: Andrew Pitonyak
'email:   andrew@pitonyak.org 
'uses:  FindCreateNumberFormatStyle
Sub InsertDateField
  Dim oDoc
  Dim oText
  Dim oVCurs
  Dim oTCurs
  Dim oDateTime
  Dim s$

  oDoc = ThisComponent
  If oDoc.SupportsService("com.sun.star.text.TextDocument") Then
    oText = oDoc.Text
    oVCurs = oDoc.CurrentController.getViewCursor()
    oTCurs = oText.createTextCursorByRange(oVCurs.getStart())
    oText.insertString(oTCurs, "Today is ", FALSE)
    ' Create the DateTime type.
    s = "com.sun.star.text.TextField.DateTime"
    ODateTime = oDoc.createInstance(s)
    oDateTime.IsFixed = TRUE
    oDateTime.NumberFormat = FindCreateNumberFormatStyle(_
      "DD. MMMM YYYY", oDoc)

    oText.insertTextContent(oTCurs,oDateTime,FALSE)
    oText.insertString(oTCurs," ",FALSE)
  Else
    MsgBox "Sorry, this macro requires a TextDocument"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you are asking this questions asks for LibreOffice, OpenOffice and Excel may I ask why you "only" ask for LibreOffice in the last sentence?

Comment: I'm using LibreOffice myself but all three should work pretty much the exact same way.

Comment: ah, ok, I see, then you should edit you're question, because this way it is too broad and the last sentence is you're actual question but it is not very prominent (at least as far as I understood how a "good" question should be asked)

Comment: I edited the question, that's what I meant with point `2)`. I'm thinking this should be possible using a macro in LO and then assigning it to the shortcut, but I don't know anything about macros in LO work.

Comment: it's not the same way it works in excel?

Comment: It should be. Do you know how to create an macro for that kinda thing in excel? So far every excel solution I needed in the past has worked on libreoffice too. It supports macros in BASIC, BeanShell, JavaScript and Python.

Comment: In Excel I use the VBA editor directly (Alt+F11), but you could just use the  macro recorder, record "any thing". Editing the newly created macro should open the macro editor. That works in Excel, should work in LibreOffice as well.

Comment: That got me in the right direction. I found a macro that does what I want, but only works with a writer document. I've edited my question and added the information. Do you know how to edit this script to work within calc/excel?

Comment: @confetti, the various office suites are generally similar.  They will read and save each others files within reason, and most common features have at least an equivalent across platforms.  However, there are plenty of differences in how things actually work, and the UIs are different.  It causes endless confusion for users when problems can't be replicated or solutions don't work as written.  Please tag with the specific app you are using.  Thanks.

Comment: @confetti have a look at MShaffer's answer, he/she wrote the macro for you...  what a nice person :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the format of cells before shortcut is simplest solution?[image: Format cell]

Format cell after shortcut does not work.

### Macro way ...

```vb
Sub Main

    Dim Doc As Object
    Dim Sheet As Object
    Dim Cell As Object
    Dim NumberFormats As Object
    Dim NumberFormatString As String
    Dim NumberFormatId As Long
    Dim LocalSettings As New com.sun.star.lang.Locale

    Doc = ThisComponent
    Sheet = Doc.Sheets(0)
    Cell = Doc.getCurrentSelection
    Column = Cell.CellAddress.Column
    Row = Cell.CellAddress.Row

    Cell.Value = Now()

    LocalSettings.Language = "en"
    LocalSettings.Country = "us"

    NumberFormats = Doc.NumberFormats
    NumberFormatString = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

    NumberFormatId = NumberFormats.queryKey(NumberFormatString, LocalSettings, True)
    If NumberFormatId = -1 Then
    NumberFormatId = NumberFormats.addNew(NumberFormatString, LocalSettings)
    End If

    MsgBox NumberFormatId
    Cell.NumberFormat = NumberFormatId

End Sub
```

Comment: using Ctrl+Shift+; gives me only gives me the date "at midnight" when I reformat? do you do it with libre office or excel? for PC or mac? what version do you use?

Comment: also for me formating the cell before inserting the time shortcut doesn't work!

Comment: LibreOffice Version: 5.1.6.2 / Ubuntu 16.04 ... i get the same result if I apply the format after using shortcut ... pre formating did not truncate the time on ctrl+; or the date on crtl+shift+;

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour @Albin described. This doesn't work for me. I'm on LibreOffice 6. In addition, this gives me "###" when I reformat.

Comment: I'm sorry, apparently the "###" appeared because the cell wasn't wide enough. Your approach worked for me. Hoping for an answer that doesn't require me to format every cell beforehand though.

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you SO much. Exactly what I needed. I removed the `MsgBox` and set this to a shortcut and it does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

For Excel (tested for MS Excel 2010 for Windows): inserting it into one cell without macro or additional software the only solution is to use 3 shortcuts after another:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>
- <kbd>space</kbd>
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

At least this will give you `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM`

From there you just have to change the user defined format to your choice: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: This would use the default date and time format, in my case this would give me `08/02/18 08:29:44PM`. I need a custom format, without changing the global default.

Comment: @confetti ah, ok, you should add this information to you're question.

Comment: I thought I was clear enough with what I said already but I'll edit it to be more clear.

Comment: You could program a keyboard shortcut to enter all the keystrokes with one shortcut.